# How to combine CRC-32 results?

Tags: ethernet, crc32

Let's say I have two numbers X = 0xABC; Y = 0xDE.
I want to calculate CRC-32 over Z, which is X concatenated to Y i.e. Z = 0xABCDE.

I have CRC(X) and CRC(Y) available. How can I compute CRC(Z) ?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`crc32_combine()`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/crc32.c#L372) in [zlib](http://zlib.net/) for the approach.

The basic idea is to use the linearity of CRCs. The CRC of `0xABC00` exclusive-or'ed with `0x000DE` is the exclusive-or of their corresponding CRCs. If I ignore the pre and post-processing (which I can for reasons that are left to the reader to derive), leading zeros do not change the CRC, so the CRC of `0xDE` is the same as the CRC of `0x000DE`. So all I need to do is calculate the effect of appending zeros when starting with the CRC of `0xABC`, in order to get the CRC of `0xABC00`. Then exclusive-or those two CRCs.

`crc32_combine()` uses matrix multiplication to compute the effect of appending *n* zeros in O(log(*n*)) time instead of O(*n*) time, so combining CRCs is very fast regardless of the lengths of the original messages.

Comment: I read your answer on google groups, [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.compression/SHyr5bp5rtc). The problem I am facing is, I am trying to implement this on hardware (FPGA). I have the parallel CRC-32 calculator for **0xABC** and **0xDE** but when I try to calculate the CRC-32 over **0xABC00** and **0x000DE** then XOR the CRCs then I get the wrong result because of the ZEROS.

Comment: You need to write a question here, with the details of what you're doing, what you're expecting, and what you're getting.